# ssis importing to an other server

Tags: excel, ssis

There is a SSIS project which takes data from oracle table and export that into xls file.But before exporting there are File System Task and Execute SQL Task which are supposed to delete xls file and after that create it again. The project looks like on images: 
 [image]

it perfectly works on a  lochalhost. But the task is to export a file to other server. Excel file path for "Excel connection manager"  is

> C:\Users\YIskende\Desktop\New folder\report.xlsx

but how to change that in such a way to make it work with an external server

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions (it depends also from SSIS and SQL Server version)
1) Package Deployment Mode: If you use a package configuration (old SSIS and SQL Server versions), you can create a Configuration database on your server where to store paths and variable values (Menu: SSIS -> Package Configurations)
[image: Package Deployment Mode]
2) Project Deployment Mode: In SQL Server 2014 version you have a Integration Services Catalogs in SQL Management Studio where deploy your project and save your values 
[image: Project Deployment Mode]